# Joda DateTimeFormatter IllegalFormatException on real device, but is working in emulator

Tags: android, jodatime

If I use this code:

```
DateTimeFormatter fmt = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("EEE dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss Z");
```

on this String:

```
Tue 29 Oct 2013 11:30:16 +0000
```

It works without an exception in the emulator, but if I start the app on a real device it outputs this exception:

```
10-29 12:30:20.870: W/System.err(751): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid format: "Tue 29 Oct 2013 11:30:16 +0000"
10-29 12:30:20.870: W/System.err(751):  at org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parseDateTime(DateTimeFormatter.java:873)
10-29 12:30:20.870: W/System.err(751):  at de.allmystery.allmyapp.fregman.KategorieObject.getDiff(KategorieObject.java:146)
10-29 12:30:20.870: W/System.err(751):  at de.allmystery.allmyapp.fregman.KategorieObject.<init>(KategorieObject.java:46)
10-29 12:30:20.870: W/System.err(751):  at de.allmystery.allmyapp.fregman.KategorieActivity.convertCat(KategorieActivity.java:261)
10-29 12:30:20.870: W/System.err(751):  at de.allmystery.allmyapp.fregman.KategorieActivity.access$0(KategorieActivity.java:259)
10-29 12:30:20.870: W/System.err(751):  at de.allmystery.allmyapp.fregman.KategorieActivity$4.run(KategorieActivity.java:152)
10-29 12:30:20.870: W/System.err(751):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1019)
```

line 146 and 147 in KategoreObject:

```
DateTimeFormatter fmt = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("EEE dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss Z");
DateTime postTime = fmt.parseDateTime(getLast_post_date());
```

Could someone help me with this error?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that the device is uses german language, so it seems that DateTimeFormatter is using also the locale german

in my case the solution was :

```
DateTimeFormatter fmt = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("EEE dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss Z").withLocale(Locale.ENGLISH);
```